# iis 10 Static Website: Deleting default site and creating completely new site (how to access new site)

Tags: iis, iis-10

This post needs help from experienced iis administrators, but must be explained in details for EXTREME newbies.

What I am doing:

- I have two computers, both running Windows 10. One is a desktop and one is a laptop.
- iis is enabled on both computers. Each computer can access the iis web server from the other and pull up a page from the other - using the ip address.
- There is no DNS or host files being used (this is by ip address only), nor do I want to use any sort of naming.
- Both computers are running an identical website, and the website files are in a different directory than the default. The structure is like this:

C:\inetpub\ROOT\myWebsite\myIndex.html
                           web.config

Changes I've made - now a few problems.

1. On both computers I have deleted the DefaultAppPool and the default website that comes installed with iis. This has not stopped the website from completely working, so adding that back seems unlikely to fix my problem.
2. I have deleted my application pool and website from iis (never deleting the actual files from the file system) several times, and added it several times. Each time I do this, my site comes back, but with the same problem I am having.
3. I have deleted all of the default documents, and the only default document listed in iis is myIndex.html.
4. myIndex.html initially displays a graphic image (using the standard  tag), and this image comes up. Sort of. See explanation below.

The problem I am having

Before I started this project, I had iis working on the desktop with the default site and app pool and simply added some of my own files with really simple text content and some pics. I had replaced the default iis splash image with my own image, and all that worked with no problem.

the image that comes up is a link to another page that has a list of links to other stuff in my website. It all works no problem there.

Now, with the setup I have now, on the desktop I was originally using (in the paragraph above) if I pull up my website locally, myIndex.html loads in the browser and my image comes up, and everything works fine.

The same is true on the laptop, when I access the site locally.

However, if I attempt to access the desktop site (using its ip address) from the laptop, it pulls up the old splash image from the default site I deleted.( I left those files there even though I deleted the site from within iis). All those files are in the default location C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

If I move those files to another directory, thus leaving C:\inetpub\wwwroot completely empty, then when I access the site on the desktop (via the ip address) from the laptop, my new site comes up without a problem.

While it seems I may have solved my problem by moving the file from the previous project, doing that does not teach me how iis is actually working, and why files from a website that no longer exists in iis are still being accessed from remote computers.

So, please teach me something about the internal workings of iis, and how it chooses to access the different application pools and websites.

Again, please word your answers for complete newbies, because I know a little but not enough to get real technical.

I have been reading posts on stackexchange.com and other sites; links to microsoft docs etc. That's not helping as those docs are expecting too much prerequisite knowledge, and speaking in terms that are not really explaining things in a way I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have described several different problems.  I will try to address each of them (contrary to S/O recommendations).

First, when you make changes, and they don't seem to show up, it is usually because of caching.  IIS always wants to cache files/configs. So does your web browser.  So, to force an accurate test, you need to dump your browser cache and cycle IIS (to make sure it drops its cache and loads new files and configs). Start there.

Second, IIS is designed for settings inheritance. Which means, each app and each folder will inherit settings and permissions from the parent, unless you override them. Overriding them can be done by files and/or IIS configs (application vs folder).  The IIS configs are the stronger of the two.

Also, the IIS config for "default files" might have come into-play for your test.  If you didn't set up MyIndex.html as the top-most default file, then IIS would look for other files first. In fact, if you don't have MyIndex.html in the list of default files, IIS would have to depend on your app to choose that as a default page (MVC routing, etc).

Comment: dumping the browser cache helped me with many of the problems.

Comment: If this gave you the answer, it would be nice to mark the question as "answered".  Then other people will know.

Comment: This did not actually answer my question. I was actually looking for a step by step answer of how to set it up, and then how to access it. I think I have it set up correctly in iis according to many articles I am reading on the internet. However, nobody is explaining how to access each of the sites in a browser. One very important piece of information I need for doing this is based on that there is not going to be any DNS server, and I don't want the users having to modify their host files. This site will be accessed by IP address only on a very small local LAN.

Comment: Stack overflow is not really the place to ask for step-by-step instructions of "how to set it up, and then access it". It is more of a place to ask a specific question and get a specific solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/tour  (section "Get answers to practical, detailed questions").  
Also, that important detail about DNS, was left out of your question.  I'm also not clear about what remaining problems you are having. It might be best to start another question on S/O.